# Can you downgrade from premium (paid) to standard (free) Google Apps?

Tags: google-workspace

I got the paid version because I thought I needed to to get domain email... but turns out this isn't the case and I really can't see what I need from the paid version.

Is it possible to downgrade without losing the account, without contacting google support?

Answer (score 6):

Directions on how to cancel if within the 30-day trial period: [link](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60755)

[More](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60229)  ("Note: You can only downgrade to the Standard Edition during the 30-day Premier Edition free trial. Once your free trial expires, all sales are final.")

EDIT: From [Google](http://google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60755): "If you'd like to cancel your Premier subscription after the free trial, you can do so at the end of your one-year subscription. As long as you don't auto-renew your Premier subscription, you'll have an opportunity to downgrade to the free Standard Edition." So, if it's past the 30 days, he has already probably paid. He will not get a refund, but will just have to wait for the premium account to expire. He will then be downgraded to the standard edition.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to downgrade now...

1. Login as Admin
2. Click "Domain settings"
3. Click "Subscriptions & Billing"
4. Click "Cancel Google Apps for Business"
5. Select "Downgrade to standard edition"

Confirming the above will downgrade your account to Free which has the limitation of up to 10 users.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not :-(

Your only option is to delete the account, wait 14 days and then recreate the account as standard account.

Comment: From Google (http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60755):

"If you'd like to cancel your Premier subscription after the free trial, you can do so at the end of your one-year subscription. As long as you don't auto-renew your Premier subscription, you'll have an opportunity to downgrade to the free Standard Edition."

So, if it's past the 30 days, he has already probably paid. He will not get a refund, but will just have to wait for the premium account to expire. He will then be downgraded to the standard edition.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it myself, as the paid version actually had worse performance for one of my domains.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Google's documentations:

> Prior to December 6, 2012, Google offered a free edition of Google Apps—also known as the Standard edition—that had a reduced set of business features. As of December 6, 2012, Google stopped offering Free edition to new customers. If you already had the Free edition, you can continue using it for free. Or to receive the full set of business features, you can upgrade your account.

Therefore if you've signed up for a new account which happens to be after 2012, there won't be a way of using Google Apps for free anymore; except for the 30 days trial period.